# CloudZoom magento integration

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento

Hi guys really need some help on this issue. I've searched all over but cant find any solution.

Using http://www.starplugins.com/cloudzoom/quickstart to add hover zoom feature on single product page. Rollover on first product thumbnail shows the same image. However on second or subsequent rollover of other images the rollover image is always the 1st image.

Media.phtml

```
<?php
$_product = $this->getProduct();
$_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
$_nativeZoom = false;
?>

<?php if (count($this->getGalleryImages()) > 0): ?>
    <div class="more-views">
        <?php /* <h2><?php echo $this->__('More Views') ?></h2> */ ?>
        <?php
        $galleryImages = $this->getGalleryImages();
        $numGalleryImages = count($galleryImages);
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($galleryImages as $_image): $i++; ?>
            <div class="<?php
                if($i == 1) {
                    echo 'first';
                }
                if($i == $numGalleryImages) {
                    echo 'last';
                }
                ?>">
                <a href="#" data-large-image="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'image', $_image->getFile()); ?>"
                   title="<?php echo $_product->getName();?>">
                    <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'thumbnail', $_image->getFile())->resize(124); ?>"
                         alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_image->getLabel()) ?>" />
                </a>
            </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>

<div id="main-image">
    <?php
    $_img = '<img class="cloudzoom" id="main-product-image" src="'.$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')->resize(450).'" data-cloudzoom="zoomImage: \''.$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image').'\'" alt="'.$this->escapeHtml($_product->getImageLabel()).'" title="'.$this->escapeHtml($_product->getImageLabel()).'" />';
    echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_img, 'image');
    ?>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery('.more-views a').click(function(){
        jQuery('#main-product-image').attr('src', jQuery(this).attr('data-large-image'));
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

jquery initialize script

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    if (jQuery('.catalog-product-view').length) {

        if (window.location.hash == '#_reviews') {
            //add scroll to down to product reviews list when pagination is used
            jQuery.scrollTo(jQuery('#reviews'), {duration: 1000, interrupt: true});
        }

        //cloudzoom configuration http://www.starplugins.com/cloudzoom/quickstart
        $('#main-product-image').CloudZoom({
            tintColor: '#6e4d56',
            tintOpacity: 0.43,
            zoomSizeMode: 'image',
            autoInside: 1000
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: As an alternative zoom approach, you could try this, it works for me: http://leveluptuts.com/tutorials/magento-community-tutorials/53-theming-magento-23-better-product-zoom.